# Some Logical error in handler in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler, postdelayed

I am beginner in android.

**What I want:**
Here I am trying to achieve that sub handler should call 10 times of every second of main handler. And that main handler should continue until 20 seconds.

**Issue:**
To check that i\I have used log but its not working. It goes into sub handler some times 8 times or some times 9 or 10.
Is there any logical error or is there any other better way to achieve this?
Thank you.

**My code:**

```
int i=0;
int cont;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;
        cont = 1;
        Log.e("main count", i + "");
        final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (cont <= 10) {
                    Log.e("sub count ", cont + "");
                    cont++;
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            }
        }, 100);
        if (!(i == 20)) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @pskink-Actually in future i want to call different methods in both main handler and other sub handler..

Comment: Why do you need multiple Handlers?

Comment: @jimmyB-I want the flaw that every single second the y method gets called multiple times  and from main handler x method gets called one time..

Comment: you're going to have to format your code and use descriptive variable names if you want us to understand what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to execute code with precise timing using a Handler because you have to measure the time yourself.
It's much easier to use the built-in classes like [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) or [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html). I'd recommend the first as it would require less changes to the code. You should pick one of the scheduleAtFixedRate() or scheduleWithFixedDelay() methods according to your requirements.

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
final ScheduledFuture mainFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       if (i < 20) {
           Log.e("main count ", i + "");
           i++;
       } else {
           mainFuture.cancel(true);// stop after 20 executions
       }          
},
0, /*initial wait time*/
1, /* time between consecutive runs */
TimeUnit.SECONDS);

final ScheduledFuture subFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       if (cont < 20 * 10) {
           Log.e("sub count ", cont + "");
           cont++;
       } else {
           subFuture.cancel(true);// stop after 200 executions
           executor.shutdown();
       }          
}, 
100, /*adjust this according to the desired sequencing of the count tasks */
100, /* time between consecutive runs */
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You could also use a single ScheduledFuture and execute the code for main count after every 10 executions of the sub count code.